# lpr prints only txt files

Tags: command-line, bash

I have made a script to automatically print all files dropped on a folder, then delete it after printing. This works fine with text files, but doc,jpg,pdf,..etc printing is failing with no result

What I need is for all types of files which are dropped there to be printed

My code:

```
MONITORDIR="/home/lawrence/Desktop/lawrence/"
inotifywait -m -r -e create --format '%w%f' "${MONITORDIR}" | while read NEWFILE
do
         /usr/bin/lpr "${NEWFILE}"
         rm "${NEWFILE}"
done
```